# piping stdout of an interactive script to its own stdin

Tags: bash, stdout, stdin

consider the following simple interactive shell script:

```
# tool.sh
echo "Good Morning."
echo "My Name is Mr. Sunshine, I am 100 years old."
echo
echo "So, what's your name?"
read name;
echo "and, whats' your age?"
read age;
echo $name, $age years old > output.txt
```

Say, this script should now be programmatically run by another script. It's as straightforward as this:

```
echo -e "Anton\n28" | bash tools.sh
```

and voilà, output.txt contains "Anton, 28 years old" now.

**The tricky part comes now:** I want to see "Mr. Sunshine, 100 years old" in the output.txt, with just opening the tool once.

The Problem here is the setting of a *pipe that parses the output of the tools and directly emits parts to its input*.

The parsing could be done like this:

```
sed -nr 's/^My Name is (.*), I am (.*) years old\.$/\1\t\2/p'
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want. *I want to see "Mr. Sunshine, 100 years old" in the output.txt, with just opening the tool once.* `echo -e "Mr. Sunshine\n100" | bash tools.sh` does only "open" `tools.sh` once and the desired result is written to `output.txt`. Your `sed` line looks like you want to read `output.txt` and feed it to your script. Is this what you want?

Comment: The code line you suggest would do the thing, however in the scenario you would not now the values 'Mr. Sunshine' and '100' beforehand. With the sed line I don't want to parse output.txt but the output of the first lines of tool.sh

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. This is a very interesting question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use named pipes for this.

```
mkfifo tools_pipe
cat tools_pipe \
    | ./tools.sh \
    | sed -rnu 's/My Name is (.*), I am (.*) years old\./\1\n\2/p' \
    > tools_pipe
rm tools_pipe # cleanup
```

A named pipe is basically a file, you can read from and write to synchronously.
To feed the output of a tool to the tool itself as input, a named pipe can be used to establish this circular connection.

Comment: This works perfectly. I think the last step inside the wrapper.sh is not needed (>tools_pipe). I guess a typo. I'm still asking myself why actually you need 'read' in the wrapper? As well as why it works even sed emits a tab seperated string (not new lines).

Comment: That is a typo, yes. I will remove it. Well you need to process the input somehow. There are of course other ways to deal with this requirement. I tried to get `cat tools_pipe | ./tools.sh | sed -rnu 's/My Name is (.*), I am (.*) years old\./\1\t\2/p' > tools_pipe` to work, but bash behaves weirdly in this case.

Comment: Perfect, I'll include this in the answer if you don't mind.